# Gmail Add-on - Incorrectly treats message as - "Spam and suspicious messages can’t be used"

Tags: google-apps-script

We are using a Gmail Add-on which triggers on email Open.

When an email is not from a verified sender it does not trigger and instead displays the following message

> Spam and suspicious messages can’t be used for recommended content or
> actions. Try searching for messages in your inbox.

[image]

Now how the add-on determines this appears to be when the sender is not verified.

[image]

I see in the below post that this is expected behaviour when the message is in SPAM but this is not the case in this scenario...

[My add-on will not run on messages in the SPAM folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63004797/my-add-on-will-not-run-on-messages-in-the-spam-folder)

This is not a spam message and our addon needs to access the email contents in order to work.

How do we override this unwanted behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

You will want to review [Why emails have spam warning labels, Messages from an unconfirmed sender](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/1366858?hl=en-GB&expand=5#zippy=%2Cmessages-from-an-unconfirmed-sender) which links to [Check if your Gmail message is authenticated](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/180707?hl=en-GB#zippy=%2Ca-message-that-ive-received-hasnt-been-authenticated).  Basically Gmail uses SPF and DKIM to verify that the mail server sending the email is authorised to send messages for that Domain.  So you need to fix it at the point you send the emails by setting up SPF or DKIM appropriately.

If that is not possible, set up a filter via "Filter messages like this" option and set up a filter and try options such as "Never send it to Spam" and "Forward it to:" and forward it to itself.

[image: GMail filter dialogue]

Comment: Hi @Dijkgraaf - we can't control this as the emails come from senders that we have nothing to do with...  Is just the contents of our Gmail inbox.  There will always be emails that fail those checks in the Inbox and we need to still use our app to process them...

Comment: @PNC Then your only options are as per the answer you've already linked to.

Comment: the difference here is that the messages are not in the SPAM folder and appears to me to be an incorrect classification by the Gmail Addon.

Comment: @PNC Is there any possibility that it was originally being classified as SPAM, but someone added a filter via "Filter messages like this" and told gmail not to send these to the SPAM folder?  Possibly that removes it from the SPAM folder, but does not reset the flag that the sender is not verified, which is also the issue in the other question.  Have you tried the fix of forwarding the message to the same mailbox? You can set up forwarding in the filter as well.

Comment: Hi @Dijkgraaf - thanks for the comments - no the emails are legitimate and have not been sent to SPAM - in the above case I think it is the SPF record that Gmail is hot happy with (a fairly common scenario).  The problem here is that our app is used by many users and although the workarounds will probably work we are after a solution that doesn't require users to have to change the default behaviour of Gmail.  If the email is not in SPAM then we are wanting the Gmail Add-on to trigger.